How to log the version of my Nuxt app on server startup?
I want to write out a log line that reads "started version 0.4.0" when I start up the server, where the version is taken from the package.json file.
I defined a module and I'm passing it the version from the nuxt.config.ts file like so:
import pkg from './package.json'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
//...
  modules: [
//...
    ['~/modules/server-startup-log', { version: pkg.version }]
  ]
})

The module's code is:
import { defineNuxtModule } from '@nuxt/kit'

export default defineNuxtModule({
    setup(options) {
        console.log(`Started version ${options.version}`);
    }
})

This only works if I run the server in dev mode, but after I build the
app it no longer prints the line on start up? Why is that? How can I get
this line to print after building as well?

log() is not executed or shows undefined()? It's not the same thing. "after I build the app it no longer prints the line on start up?" - how do you run it?

I run it like so: node .output/server/index.mjs
